# how to add a picture on notification bar in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

How do you put this image http://1.androidauthority.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/ics-notifications.jpg) into the notification bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i figure out, you need new api for Android 3.0+  the new Notification, you can set up any drawable :)

```
 Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
     .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_sample, tickerText,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Where R.drawable.stat_sample points to your image.

More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: but that its working with Drawable, what happens if i want contact picture?i have the drawable or bitmap, but notification only accept int

Comment: the int is the reference id to your drawable

Comment: yeah, i know but what happen if i want use contact picture? i cant have my contacts pictures on my "drawable" folder, so i i get the contact picture with a query to the database, so its posible use a placeholder or something?